# jQuery toggle text in div based on checkbox state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still in the process of learning jQuery and have run into something I can't seem to solve. I'm trying to toggle the label of a checkbox in a div located elsewhere on the page. So far I've managed to append the label only if the checkbox is unchecked, but I can't figure out how to remove the text *for that filter only* if it becomes unchecked. Any advice?

JQUERY:

```
  $('.filter-single').on('click', function () {
    if ($('.filter-single input').is(':checked')) {
      $('<li>'+$(this).text()+' / </li>').appendTo('.filters-current');
    } else {
    // what goes here?
    }
  });
```

FILTER HTML:

```
 <div class="checkbox filter-single">
   <input type="checkbox" value=".rain"/>
   <label>Rain</label>
 </div>
```

LABEL HTML:

```
<div class="filter-details">
    <span class="filter-title">Filters:</span>
    <ul class="filters-current"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tjdragon/rFz67/)**

You can use [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) to look for the corresponding LI and then [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/), also i would assign the click handler to the input itself instead of the container like this:

```
$('.filter-single input').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('<li>' + $(this).next("label").text() + ' /</li>').appendTo('.filters-current');
    } else {
        $(".filters-current").find("li:contains('" + $(this).next("label").text() + " /')").remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Learn something new every day :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$('.filters-current').html("");
```

This should set the inner html as empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to implement several filters, if not Taleeb's answer should work. If you are indeed looking for several, you could try something like this:

```
var filters={};  
        $('input:checkbox').on('click', function () {
            var filter_name = $(this).siblings("label").text();
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                filters[filter_name]=true;
            }else{
                filters[filter_name]=false;
            }
            displayFilters();
      });

    function displayFilters(){
        $(".filters-current").html("");
        console.log(filters)
        for (var filter in filters){
            if(filters[filter]){
                $(".filters-current").append("<li>"+filter+"</li>")
            }
        }
    }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/X65wv/